# Convert DocumentReference property into String from Firestore

Tags: json, dart, google-cloud-firestore, data-manipulation

I have a list of elements (Tickets) and since I can't convert the json because of one property (in this case user_id) being a document reference, how can I achieve to change only this property into a string (user_id)? It is written in Dart.

Code that won't work with DocumentReference:

```
QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot.docs
          .map((doc) => Ticket.fromJson(doc.data()))
          .toList();
```

fromJson:

```
Ticket _$TicketFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Ticket(
      id: json['id'] as String? ?? '',
      createdAt: DateTime.parse(json['created_at'] as String),
      price: (json['price'] as num).toDouble(),
      userId: json['user_id'] as String,
    );
```

I know that I can get the String path of the DocumentReference by using .getPath(). But how can alter it inside the map in the query above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

```
 final result = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) {
    final ticket = doc.data();
    final dR = ticket['user_id'] as DocumentReference;
    final path = dR.path;
    ticket.update('user_id', (dynamic value) => path);
    return Ticket.fromJson(ticket);
  }).toList();
```

Maybe there is a more elegant way to accomplish the same result.